# What happens to /proc/self/fd/4 in this example?

Tags: linux, proc

With bash 3.00.15(1):

```
$ ls /proc/self/fd 4<&1
0 1 2 3 4
$ echo | ls /proc/self/fd 4<&1
0 1 2 3 4
$ ls() { /bin/ls $*; }
$ ls /proc/self/fd 4<&1
0 1 2 3 4
$ echo | ls /proc/self/fd 4<&1   # Unexpected output
0 1 2 3
```

This seems like a bash bug, as the behavior in dash and zsh is different (and the behavior in bash is not what I expect).  Change the dup'd descriptor to 5, and the final output is as expected.

Any thoughts as to what is happening to cause this behavior?

Comment: On my Debian/Sid `echo | ls -l /proc/self/fd 4>&1` shows the fd 4, both with `zsh` and with `bash` shells, and also with `sash`